# Total Difference between selected rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a dataset like below

[image: Data]

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[testTable](
[ID] [int] NULL,
[Type] [varchar](50) NULL,
[Time] [datetime] NULL)

 INSERT INTO testTable
(Id,Type,Time)
SELECT '1','Start','Feb 22 2018  6:02AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','Move','Feb 22 2018  7:10AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','End','Feb 22 2018  7:21AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','Idle','Feb 22 2018  7:31AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','Idle','Feb 22 2018  7:35AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','Start','Feb 22 2018  8:06AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','Move','Feb 22 2018  8:25AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','Move','Feb 22 2018  8:36AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','End','Feb 22 2018  8:48AM' UNION ALL
SELECT '1','Start','Feb 22 2018 10:06AM'
```

I need to get the TOTAL difference between the Start and End for the day. If the Start is ongoing overnight then the cut off time should be 00:00hrs.

Example:-
It should be (End-Start)+(End-Start)+(2018-02-23 00.00.00 - Start).

**2 starts (or ends) can be entered one after the other**

Comment: [Forum Etiquette: How to post a T-SQL Question](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Best+Practices/61537/). Post your data in a consumable format, and provide expected results. Also, what have you tried so far? It'll would be helpful if you tag the version of SQL Server you're using as well.

Comment: That edit doesn't help. Have a look at the link on how to provide expected results (and not post data as an image, which no one can use).

Answer (score 0):

This is somewhat of a guess, as the OP hasn't specified their Expected Results. I therefore, have no idea what "`EndTime - StartTime`" should actually be (number of seconds perhaps? What I guessed).

Again, if this isn't right, then post **expected results** and reply to my comments. We're not mind readers here. :)

```
WITH Leads AS(
    SELECT ID,
           [Type],
           [Time],
           ISNULL(LEAD([Time]) OVER (PARTITION BY CONVERT(date, [Time]) ORDER BY [Time]), DATEADD(DAY, 1,CONVERT(date, [Time])))  AS NextTime
    FROM testTable
    WHERE [Type] in ('Start','End'))
SELECT ID,
       SUM(DATEDIFF(SECOND,[Time], NextTime)) AS TotalSeconds
FROM Leads
WHERE [Type] = 'Start'
GROUP BY ID;
```

*Edit: It's worth noting that this also **assumes** that 2 starts (or ends) won't be entered one after the other. The sample data doesn't show that happening, but, of course, that doesn't mean the real data is as clean.*

Comment: I assumed SQL experts would understand (EndTime - StartTime) is time difference i.e. duration (it can be in seconds or any time format, I can do that conversion)

Comment: 2 starts (or ends) can be entered one after the other...Thanks for pointing that out

Comment: @NavedMir "SQL Experts" aren't mind readers. Difference could be anything when dealing with time, hence why it's always good to provide expected results and why I had to **guess** what you wanted. `DATEDIFF(MINUTE...` and `DATEDIFF(SECOND...` would produce very difference results (and I don't mean that one would be 60x larger).

Answer (score 0):

Try this alternative solution, it doesn't use `lead` or `lag`:

```
;with cte as (
    select *, ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by datepart(day,[time]) order by [time]) [rn]
    from #testTable
    where [type] in ('start','end')
)

select CAST(startTime as date) [Date],
       SUM([DifferenceInMinutes]) [DifferenceInMinutes]
from (
    select [c1].[id],
           [c1].[time] [startTime],
           ISNULL([c2].[time], cast(dateadd(day, 1, [c1].[time]) as date)) [endTime],
         DATEDIFF(minute, [c1].[time],ISNULL([c2].[time], cast(dateadd(day, 1, [c1].[time]) as date))) [DifferenceInMinutes]
    from cte [c1] left join cte [c2]
    on [c1].rn = [c2].[rn] - 1 and datepart(day,[c1].[time]) = datepart(day,[c2].[time])
    where [c1].[type] = 'start'
) a group by CAST(startTime as date)
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use LAG() function in a query with GROUP BY just like any other query. The only difference is that the columns allowed in the window (OVER) and in the LAG are the ones allowed in SELECT after a GROUP BY:

Example Table:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE foo AS
SELECT date::date, session_id, upload_usage, download_usage, 
total_usage_on_a_day
FROM ( VALUES
( '10/21/2014', '0007994b', 37578561   , 6800209   , 44378770 ),
( '10/22/2014', '0007994b', 218113296  , 85272007  , 303385303 ),
( '10/23/2014', '0007994b', 552228616  , 252390680 , 804619296 ) ,
( '10/24/2014', '0007994b', 799772020  , 391196041 , 1190968061 ),
( '10/25/2014', '0007994b', 1047233978 , 529908804 , 1577142782 ),
( '10/26/2014', '0007994b', 1294608258 , 668515778 , 1963124036 ),
( '10/27/2014', '0007994b', 1066656794 , 557318645 , 2573613674 ),
( '10/27/2014', '00079e4e', 12949219   , 7265243   , 20214462 ),
( '10/28/2014', '00079e4e', 203871297  , 114308478 , 318179775 ),
( '10/29/2014', '00079e4e', 445466682  , 251486943 , 696953625 ),
( '10/30/2014', '00079e4e', 183499477  , 109643736 , 893143213 )
) AS t( date, session_id, upload_usage, download_usage, total_usage_on_a_day 
);
```

Example Query:

```
select 
date,
session_id, 
sum(upload_usage) as upload,
sum(download_usage) as download,
sum(total_usage_on_a_day) as total_as_cumm,
sum(total_usage_on_a_day) 
- coalesce(lag(sum(total_usage_on_a_day)) over (partition by session_id 
order by date), 0)
as expected_difference
from jiodba.s_crc_zda_mon_conn_usage 
where gpart = '1100043958' 
and zzaccess_ntwk_id = 'FTTH' 
group by session_id, date
order by session_id, date 
limit 100 ;
```

Comment: Not sure where that `CREATE` statement came from, but it's not T-SQL, nor representative of the OP's data. Possibly MySQL? The Query is fine, but `CREATE TEMP TABLE`,`CREATE TABLE AS` and  `date:date` is not valid T-SQL syntax. :)